# Telosys - default values not getting generated for fields

Tags: jpa, code-generation, telosys

I am using Java7 persistence with Spring Data JPA template to generate my DAL classes using Telosys generator. While my database has default values set for all the columns, my template fails to generate the same in my @column annotation.
Kindly suggest if this can be fixed in the template or any other template you suggest.

Comment: What version of Telosys are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.x

Answer (score 0):

In Telosys 3.x   "columnDefinition = xxx DEFAULT xx" is not handled by "$jpa" object.

It is supported in Telosys 4.0.

So you have 2 options :

- you can switch to Telosys 4
- you can managed the column definition yourself in the template (for example with a Velocity macro or with your own specific Java class)

Comment: Thank you for your response Igu. I am eagerly waiting for Telosys 4 eclipse plugin